# Concat string without having leading and trailing spaces and only when there are values in the fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I have a table from where I would like to concat address fields by separating on ',' or ' '. But there is a scenario that all fields do not have value in them.

As per screenshot, there can be fields where values are blank, in that case due to ', ' the value just populated as , , and would also lead to trailing and leading spaces.

**Initial Approach:** (

```
concat(trim(concat(trim(faddress1), ', ', trim(faddress2))), ', ', trim(fcity), ', ', trim(fstate), ', ', trim(fzip))) stop_location_code,
```

We should do some conditional logic so we aren't adding spaces when a component is null

Tried second approach to see if some conditional logic can be done, though it removed the spaces issue. All the values are concatentated together without space (refer screenshot)

**Second Way:**

```
 concat(isnull(trim(faddress1),''),isnull(trim(faddress2),''),isnull(trim(fcity),''),isnull(trim(fstate),''),isnull(trim(fzip),'')) as test,`
```

[image]

Example: 
If faddress1 = abc, faddress2 = def, fcity = ghi so on
return "abc def ghi etc.."

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2017+, consider `CONCAT_WS`.

Comment: @Larnu In that case if any value in blank, then you would like as def__abc_ghi

Comment: Don't use `''` strings, use `NULL`. The reason you're having a problem is partly because of your `ISNULL(String,'')` expressions.

Comment: `SELECT CONCAT_WS('_',a,b,c,d) FROM (VALUES('a','b',NULL,'d')) V(a,b,c,d);` returns `'a_b_d'`, not `'a_b__d'`: [db<>fidde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7e6da0fe29aab5c9d855b0081e2122e4)

Comment: @Larnu noted but concat_ws is not possible as older version, any other thoughts?

Comment: neither is `trim()`

Comment: If you can't use `CONCAT_WS` you can't use `TRIM` as they were added in the same version; which means you would get an error above. Which version you actually using?

Comment: @Larnu yes what you both said is right, it was mistake. As far as version its a legacy prod system hosted in sql azure, not exactly aware of version. Other thing is I get values as __AKENY_IA_ (double underscore in front as first column are empty strings) , the fields used in the concat do not have null values but have empty strings, due to which concat_ws continues

Comment: @Larnu on using Nullif ('a', '') , will return null if both are same then concat_ws would work, concat_ws('_',nullif(trim(faddress1),''),nullif(trim(faddress2),''),nullif(trim(fcity),''),nullif(trim(fstate),''),nullif(trim(fzip),'')) as test2,